# Magento2 REST API 400 bad request specific error codes

Tags: magento2, rest-api

In Magento2, while returning an error from a rest endpoint, i can throw an exception like this

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(__('No centers matching search criteria'))
```

It will throw an error like

[image]

My requirement, is to add an error code along with response i.e.

```
{
"message": "No centers matching search criteria.",
"error_code":101
"trace": null
}
```

Any ideas how this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass **error code** as a 2nd parameter as given below:

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception(__('No centers matching search criteria'),101)
```

Then the response should be looks like as:

```
{
"message": "No centers matching search criteria.",
"code": 101,
"trace": null
}
```

Comment: this will return 200  ok with error message, i want to handle using magento's exceptions

Comment: ooh, I did not recognized that. I have modified the answer. Please check this may works for you.

Comment: oh thats interesting, will try and get back! thanks

Comment: can the message in array format ?